# How to update formControl values automatically from other formControl values in reactive forms angular 2?

Tags: arrays, angular, autocomplete, angular-material2, angular-reactive-forms

```
this.myForm = fb.group({
         name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
         date: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
         address: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
        ,
         items: fb.array([
             this.initItem(),
         ])
     });

initItem() {
  return this.fb.group({
      item: [''],
      itemType: [''],
      amount: [''],
      presentRate:this.myForm,
      total:['']
  });
```

When submitting the form,this item property will be stored by an object.
Example object:

```
item{
  itemName:"name",
  itemRate:1000,...}
```

How can i use the properties of item object and patch the values in my initItem() methord properties?My scenario is like ,When user select a value from dropdown,the item will get updated and i would like to display the values obtained from the item in other formControls.
Example:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myForm.controls.items.controls; let i=index">
           <div [formGroupName]="i">
             <md2-autocomplete [items]="products"
                       item-text="product"
                       (change)="handleChange($event)"
                       placeholder="Product purchased"
                       formControlName="item"
                       >
             </md2-autocomplete>
             <md-input-container >
               <input md-input placeholder="Present rate" [value]="presentRate" formControlName="presentRate"  >
             </md-input-container>
```

I would like to update the values on presentRate input box automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm supposing that you're trying to update the value for each `presentRate` based on the selected value in `md2-autocomplete`. If I'm correct the following should work:

**Template:**

```
(change)="handleChange($event, i)"
```

**Component:**

```
handleChange($event: any, i: index) {
  const control: AbstractControl = myForm.get(`items.${i}.presentRate`);
  let newVal: any;

  if ($event.value) {
    newVal = $event.value.rate;
  } else {
    newVal = '';
  }

  control.patchValue(newVal);
}
```

Comment: `handleChange($event: any, i: index) {
  const control: AbstractControl = this.myForm.get(`items.${i}.presentRate`);
  control.patchValue($event.value.rate);` I did like this and it works but i'm getting an error while changing value from dropdown.

Comment: Is this the problem with md2-autocomplete?

Comment: Well, you have to check if the value is valid before try to access **any** *property*. Put a `console.log($event)` to see what's happening.

Comment: Yea its working!!!  `if ($event.value) {
    control.patchValue($event.value.rate);
  }
  else
  control.patchValue('');`

Comment: I added an else condition to clear the value if the event.value is null.Is it the right way?

Answer (score 4):

You can subscribe to `valueChanges` of a form control and call `setValue` on another form control.

```
this.myForm.get('myControlName').valueChanges
.subscribe(val => 
  this.myForm.get('myOtherControlName').setValue(val)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.But how is it possible to access a formControl in a formArray?

Comment: `this.myForm.get('myOtherControlName.3.inArray')` gets the 2nd `inArray` control element in the `myOtherControlName` array.

Comment: `initItem() {
  return this.fb.group({
      item: [''],
      itemType: [''],
      amount: [''],
      presentRate:this.this.myForm.get('myOtherControlName.3.inArray'),
      total:['']
  });` is it correct?

Comment: I think you meant [`.setValue(val)`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setvalue), because [`updateValueAndValidity`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updatevalueandvalidity) doesn't work like that.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride It's likely this changed since then. Forms weren't very stable back then.